# views filter autocomplete not working without taxonomy value

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have created a view with contextual filter taxonomy :-> display all when value not available. and an exposed filter content title with auto complete widget.
my view and exposed filter is working fine when i pass a taxonomy in url but i does not work without taxonomy.

any one know this problem?
[image: View with contextual and exposed filter]